# Consuming OData from jquery ajax Error : "SCRIPT1004: SCRIPT1004: Expected ';'"

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, odata

I created a odata web api using below link
[Microsoft Doc OData V4 Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint)

So my solution contains two project

1. ODATAWebApi
2. WebApp

Please find the code 
WebApp Code

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://localhost:44340/',
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    "headers": {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert('Data: ' + data);
    },
    error: function (request, error) {
        console.log("Request: " + JSON.stringify(request));
        alert("Request: " + JSON.stringify(request));
    }
});
```

});

WebApi Code

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");

            config.MapODataServiceRoute(
                routeName: "odata",
                routePrefix: null,
                model: builder.GetEdmModel());

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }

// GET: odata/Products
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        return db.Products;
    }
```

When I am trying to consume this odata using jquery ajax 
I am getting below error

```
1) Request: {"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"load"}

2) SCRIPT1004: SCRIPT1004: Expected ';'     localhost:44340 (1,18)
    {"@odata.context":"https://localhost:44340/$metadata",
      "value":[{"name":"Products","kind":"EntitySet","url":"Products"}]}
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to help from my colleague i was able to do it..

If you are using OData V4,

> replace using System.Web.Http.OData; With using
>   Microsoft.AspNet.OData;

Add the below code in the WebApiConfig.Register method

```
        ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");

        var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(corsAttr);

        config.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", "api", builder.GetEdmModel());
```

Below is the Ajax Code

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://localhost:44340/api/Products(1)',
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',      
    success: function (data) {
        alert('Data: ' + data);
    },
    error: function (request, error) {
        console.log("Request: " + JSON.stringify(request));
        alert("Request: " + JSON.stringify(request));
    }
});
```

URL:https://localhost:44340/api/Products(1)
This worked..